# React send child object into parent array and submit form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Newbie issues: Building a shopping cart, I have a form in a modal.
The submit button is that of the modal (outside the form tags), but seems to be sending the form to the handleOnSubmit handler. However, apart from closing the modal, I am unable to update the productBought and productName state values.
Ideally, I would like to push the basket[] content  (from InputList class) unto a new array in the parent (AsyncAwaitLocalhost), after which I can submit the entire purchase to an API.
refs are deprecated and various other flavors of sharing data are failing me.
My challenges are:
(i) How can I share the push the basket object to a waiting parent state object?
and
(ii) How can I submit the form after console logging the form objects?

Thanks.

`AsyncAwaitLocalhost.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import "./App.css"
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap"
import Form from "./Form.jsx"

class AsyncAwaitLocalhost extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sharedVar: "init",
            jsonContent: [],
            isOpen: null,
            productBought: 0,
            productName: "anItem"

        }
        this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    updateShared(shared_value) {
        this.setState({ sharedVar: shared_value });
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        // GET request using fetch with async/await
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/cakes');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ jsonContent: data.cakes, greeting: this.state.greeting, newGreeting: this.state.newGreeting })
    }

    openModal = (index) => () => this.setState({ isOpen: index });

    closeModal = () => this.setState({ isOpen: null });

    handleCloseModal() {
        this.setState({ isOpen: null });
    }

    handleOnSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ productBought: event.target.name.value })
        this.setState({ productName: event.target.name.value })
        console.log("Inside handleOnSubmit: " + this.state.productBought)
        this.handleCloseModal();
    }

    render() {

        const { jsonContent } = this.state;
        const { sharedVar } = this.state;
        const { productBought } = this.state;
        const { productName } = this.state;
        console.log("shared var in parent: " + sharedVar)
        console.log("productBought in parent: " + productBought)

        const Cake = ({ name, id, text, image, comment, price, dbutton, dmodal }) => (
            <div className="rounded-well">
                <div>
                    <img src={image} width="120px" alt={name} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>{name}</p>
                    <p>{text}</p>
                    <p>{comment}</p>
                    <p>{id}</p>
                    <p>{price}</p>
                    <div> {this.state.sharedVar}</div>
                    <div>{dbutton}</div>
                    <div id="dModal" className="dModalClosed">{dmodal}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        return (
            <div className="card text-center m-3">
                Showing HTTP Requests, CSS , Data Transfer &amp; Modals
                <h5 className="card-header">See Cakes</h5>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <div>
                        {this.state.jsonContent.map((cake, index) => (
                            <Cake
                                image={cake.image}
                                text={cake.text}
                                key={index}
                                price={"£" + cake.price + ".00"}
                                dbutton={<Button onClick={this.openModal(index)}>See more</Button>}
                                dmodal={
                                    <Modal id={cake.name} show={this.state.isOpen === index}
                                        onHide={this.closeModal} className="image-container">
                                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                            <Modal.Title>{cake.text}</Modal.Title>
                                        </Modal.Header>
                                        <Modal.Body>
                                            <div>
                                                <img src={cake.image} width="300px" alt={cake.name} />
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                            <p>{cake.text}</p>
                                            <p>{cake.comment}</p>
                                            <div>
                                                <form id={cake.name} method="POST" action="#" onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit} >
                                                    {<Form dataFromParent={this.state.jsonContent[index]} onChange />}
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </Modal.Body>
                                        <Modal.Footer>
                                            <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                                                Cancel
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button form={cake.name} type="submit" variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>
                                                Add to basket
                                            </Button>
                                        </Modal.Footer>
                                    </Modal>
                                }
                            />
                        ))}
                        <div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { AsyncAwaitLocalhost };
```

`Form.jsx`

````
import React from 'react';
class InputList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {     
      bought: 0,
      sharedVar: "input field",
      cakeItems:{},
      basket: [],
      input: 0,
      item: ""
    }
  }

    handleChange(index, e) {
      const value = e.target.value
      this.props.onChange(index, {...this.props.data[index], buy: value})
      this.state.bought = value
      this.state.cakeItems = {item: this.props.data[0].name, number: this.state.bought}
      this.state.basket.push(this.state.cakeItems)
    }
    
    render() { 

      const { bought } = this.state;
      const {cakeItems}  = this.state;
      const {basket}  = this.state;
      const { sharedVar } = this.state;
      const { item } = this.state;
      // this.state.sharedVar = this.props.dataFromParent[0].name
      console.log("pre-bought: " + bought);
      console.log("Shared var in input class: " + sharedVar);
      console.log("basket in InputClass: " + JSON.stringify(basket))
      return (
        <div>
          

            Buy: &nbsp;
            {this.props.data.map((d, i) => <input key="0" value={d.buy} name="productBought" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />)}
            {this.props.data.map((d, i) => <input key="1" type="hidden" value={d.name} name="productName" />)}
            
            <>
              &nbsp; To buy: {bought}
            </>
            
        
        </div>
        
      )
    }
  }
  
  class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        basket: [],
        sharedVar: "form field",
        usrBasket: {
          buy: 1,
          id: "randomStr",
          items: [{buy: 1, item: ""}],
          value_key: "",
          nuArry: []
        },
        input: {}
      }
    }

    loadStuff() {
      this.setState({
        data: [this.props.dataFromParent]
      })
        // console.log('got some stuff from the server in Form: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.dataFromParent))
    }
    
    handleChange(index, value) {
      console.log('data changed!', value)
      const data = [...this.state.data]
      data.splice(index, 1, value)
      this.setState({
        data, 
      })
      
      this.state.basket = this.state.cakeItems
      console.log("basket in FormClass: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.basket))
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.loadStuff()
    }
    render() {

      const {basket}  = this.state;
      const { value_key } = this.state;
      this.state.value_key = "new vk";
      console.log("value_key in Form: " + value_key);

      const { sharedVar } = this.state;
      this.state.sharedVar = "Hello greeting";
      console.log("sharedVar in Form: " + sharedVar); 
      
      return (
        <div>
              <InputList data={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      );
    
    }
  }

export default Form```

<br>
````

Answer (score 1):

Haa, the newbie life...!

So after more study and getting to learn the entire framework better the solution is thus.

(i) How can I share the push the basket object to a waiting parent state object?

- Create classes  - (some people argue for functional  components) that are distinct and do the one thing well. The Form component renders the modal, collects the form values and submits those values to the parent through props.

In Parent, make ready to receive child props

`<Cakes onSubmitChild={this.getFormValues} />`

Then send the values to the parent component from Child like this:

`this.props.onSubmitChild(this.state.productField)`

(ii) How can I submit the form after console logging the form objects?
The Parent has the submit to server button. After the Child has submitted the form values to the Parent, it is left to create a JSON object and submit it to the server using AJAX (or whatever the coder prefers).
Note that there will be CORS issues to iron out on the server side to resolve this, but I recommend the [cors library](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) in npm.